# Telegram bot pin a message automatically

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

```
send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage? chat_id=' + group_name + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + text_to_send_in_the_group

response = requests.get(send_text)
```

This code works well and I am able to forward a message into my chat. But how can I pin this latter message ? I would like to pin it to make it even more visible.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

When you send a message on success a [`message`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) object is returned, save the `message_id` and the `chat.id` and use those values to pin the message with [`pinChatMessage`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#pinchatmessage)